# unbound combo to navigate records

Tags: ms-access

I have two tables as shown below.

Table1 - Master

```
Id | Organisation Id | Organisation Name | Product Name
 1 |   1011            | Latel Ltd.        | A4 Paper
 2 |   2053            | Rahos Ltd.        | Files & Folder
 3 |   3752            | Rhinos Ltd.       | Pens & Pencils
```

Table2 - Receiving . As of now, the table is blank

```
    Organisation id  |  Price
```

I want to create a form for the user to make him enter values for the table "Receiving". I have created a form like this

```
   Organisation ID :  .......... (Combo box)
   Organisation Name : ...............
   Input Price .................

       Save
```

The Organisation ID rowsource are (select master.[organisation id] from master)

When the user selects a value from "organisation id" combo box, I want the corresponding [organisation name] values to come automatically from master table. And then the user will input only price and save.

I tried the below formula in control source of [organisation name] but it shows error "#Name"

```
 i.e. Dlookup("[organisation name]","[master]","[organisation id]=" & form!formname![organisation id])
```

Answer (score 1):

First: You really should not be storing this information in a child table. In a relational database, you should store the Primary Key value from your [master] table, and then use queries or such to pull out human-readable data.

You may already be doing this, but it's not clear, so I thought I'd mention it.

Change your Combo's Rowsource to this:

`select master.[organisation id], master.[organisation name] from master`

Then set the Combo's properties as such:

- Column Count: **2**
- Column Widths: **1;1**

This will show both columns to the user. If you do **NOT** want to show the second column, set the

- Column Widths: **1,0**

Now in the **AfterUpdate** event of the Organisation ID combo:

```
Me.[organisation name control] = me.[your combo].Columns(1)
```

Columns are zero-based, so Columns(1) refers to the second column of your combo.

Finally, I'd encourage you to avoid spaces in your column and table names. For example, [organisation name] should instead by OrganisationName, and [organisation id] should be OrganisationID.

Comment: I get the error microsoft access cannot find the object "me" when I select the value from the combo box

Comment: This solution should work... you should check the name of your combos and fields...

I would further suggest that in the **After Update** event you add a little extra code to handle nulls.

`Me.[organisation name control] = nz(me.[your combo].Columns(1),"")`

This will ensure no weird access errors come up if your Combo is `NULL`

Comment: I'm still getting the error. Can you confirm it should be. Me.[text box name of field organisation name] and the second one is Me.[comboname]??

Comment: Also, please confirm whether i shall add the operator "=" preceding the code in afterupdate event

Comment: Me.[organisation name control] is the name of the Textbox control on your form. It may be named something like "Field01", if you've not properly named your controls.

Comment: "Also, please confirm whether i shall add the operator "=" preceding the code in afterupdate event" - You should set the AfterUpdate event tag to [Event Procedure], and you should use the VBA Editor to include code there. While Access allows you to do things like you're describing (i.e. set the value of a field directly), you should not do that, and instead should use the Event stub to handle it.